# Trying to develop a sliding drawer type View in android?

Tags: java, android, slidingdrawer

I am working on an app which requires me to make a layout something like this:

[image]

Here you could see a black button like view at the right bottom . I want this button to work as a sliding drawer type view.

when I drag this button this would happen:

[image]

How could I implement this .Please someone help me with this .

Where could I start from (Please give some link to source or example)?

Answer (score 0):

i cant see ur images so edit ur link and try this one. http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented my own drawer after reading this very good article :

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-damn-that-sliding-drawer/

Good luck.